# How to Remove Price from woocoomerce widgets?

Tags: php, woocommerce

with the help of Loic i have been able to remove the prices the category page but I also realized that I have widgets that have prices as well...top rated, best seller, etc...

I am assuming(most likely incorrectly) that i would use something similar to the following:

remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );

I have been trying to figure out what hooks i need to work with to accomplish this but I am still way to new to this.

Any pointing in the right direction would be awesome.

thanks
Adrian

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the WooCommerce template `templates/template content-widget-product.php`.  You can override it with your own version and remove the line that prints the product price.  Copy it to your theme folder yourtheme/woocommerce/content-widget-product.php.  Here is the section of code I am referring to with the commented out product price.

```
<?php if ( ! empty( $show_rating ) ) : ?>
        <?php echo wc_get_rating_html( $product->get_average_rating() ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php //echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_product_item_end', $args ); ?>
```

I don't see anyway of accomplishing this filters so overwriting the template seems like the only way to do it.